# Best practices for handling IDisposable

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have a class hierarchy, each member of which may create `IDisposable` objects.

I added a `List<IDisposable>` property to the base class in this hierarchy, to which I add any disposable objects on creation. The root `Dispose` method iterates through this list and calls `Dispose` for each item in its list and clears the list. In the application, I explicitly call the top object's `Dispose` method, causing disposal to cascade through the hierarchy.

This works, but is there a better way? Am I unwittingly duplicating some functionality already present in the framework?

(Note - the objects in question have a lifetime that precludes just wrapping them in a `using` block or disposing of them in the same methodwhere they are created.)

**Edit**

Just for clarification - I'm only keeping those objects around that need to be kept. Some are disposed of in the same method where they are created, but many are used in such a way that this isn't possible.

Comment: Why do you have so many `IDisposable`s?

Comment: I'm creating and maintaining a lot of unmanaged resources - images, etc - that are updated out-of-band by unmanaged code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So long as you implement the disposable pattern correctly (as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw.aspx)), this method is fine.

As far as I know, only `using` statements have special support for `IDisposable` - there isn't anything in the framework that replicates what you are doing.

Answer (score 14):

No that is correct. `IDisposable` is designed to free up unmanaged resources and should be called as soon as possible after you have finished with the instance. It's a common misconception that this is unnecessary, or that the finailizer will do this automatically when the object is garbage collected. It does not.

The correct pattern for `IDisposable` is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=VS.100).aspx), and included below for quick reference.

```
public class Resource : IDisposable 
{
    // Dispose() calls Dispose(true)
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    // NOTE: Leave out the finalizer altogether if this class doesn't 
    // own unmanaged resources itself, but leave the other methods
    // exactly as they are. 
    ~Resource() 
    {
        // Finalizer calls Dispose(false)
        Dispose(false);
    }

    // The bulk of the clean-up code is implemented in Dispose(bool)
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) 
        {
            // free managed resources
        }
        // free native resources here if there are any
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about arbitrary `IDisposable` objects, I don't believe it exists.

The `System.ComponentModel.Container` class implements cascading Dispose, but requires the elements to implement `IComponent`.  If you control your `IDisposable` objects you could make them implement `IComponent` - it only requires implementing a single property `Site` that can return `null`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea - the `IComponent` interface is intended for non-visual components intended to be used in a RAD designer, which seems unlikely in a general class hierarchy.

Comment: @Greg, I'm pointing out its existence rather than recommending it for a given scenario.  But if you don't think it's a good idea, maybe you could explain why?

Comment: @Joe Good info. I should have mentioned that some of this runs on the compact framework, where IComponent doesn't appear to be supported.

Comment: @Joe - As I said, implementing `IComponent` indicates that the object can be used in a RAD designer (i.e. dropped as a component on a windows form) and should have the associated design-time support for that scenario. That is probably not the case for most class hierarchies. Have a read of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1dk63b.aspx and its linked pages for more information.

Comment: @Greg - useful to have this info as it helps to assess whether the recommendation applies to a given scenario.  In this case, I'm still not convinced - thare are IComponent classes in the Framework that are not mainly intended for use in a RAD designer - e.g. System.Diagnostics.Process.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a situation where the [visitor](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternVisitor.aspx#_self1) pattern could be appropriate. Although I never understand the claim that it extends your classes and leaves them unchanged, because I only know examples where classes should have an `AcceptVisitor` method or the like. BTW, it's not a pattern I like because it is complex and tends to clutter code.

Comment: Yeah, that *is* complex. My carpal tunnel is acting up just thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

If one object will create many other IDisposable objects and maintain ownership of them throughout its existence, the pattern you describe can be a good one.  It may be enhanced by having your class implement method "T RegDispos<T>(T thing) where T:IDisposable;" which will add a disposable to the list and return it.  One can thus take care of the creation and cleanup of a resource in the same statement, by replacing a statement like "someField = someDisposType.CreateThing();" with "someField = RegDispos(someDisposType.CreateThing());".

If your class doesn't expose a public constructor (requires outsiders use factory methods), and if you're either using vb.net or are willing to use thread-static fields, you can even combine initialization and cleanup with declaration (e.g. "var someField = RegDispos(someDisposType.CreateThing());").  For this to be safe, the constructor must be invoked within a try/catch or try/finally block that can call Dispose on created sub-objects if construction fails.  Because field initializers in C# don't have access to constructor parameters (a weakness in the language, IMHO) the only way to implement such a pattern is to have a factory method create the list and put it into a thread-static variable which can then be read by a static RegDispos method.