# Delete or dispose disposable from a class

Tags: c#

I've got a need to store a disposable object as a class member. This is HttpClient which is disposable and I can either dispose it manually or put it into using(var client=new ....). Now imagine such situation:

```
public class Session
{
    private HttpClient m_httpClient;

    public Session()
    {
       m_httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }
}
```

How do I dispose `HttpClient`? Does the garbage collector when deleting session takes care of disposable `HttpClient` also ? There are destructors in C++. In C# it's not neccessary. Should I make session object disposable too then? Thank you.

Comment: you can use `using()` for such situation

Comment: Typically if you have a resource which needs disposing as an instance field, your class should implement `IDisposable` too, and call `Dispose` on the field when the container is disposed.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed

Comment: @JonSkeet What is wroing If I call `HttpClient` `Dispose` in `Session` Finalizer ?

Comment: This question [already has an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538494/types-that-own-disposable-fields-should-be-disposable-how-to-solve-this-warning)

Comment: @AramKocharyan: Well what if (as is quite natural) you want the client to be disposed without having to wait for garbage collection? (Failure to dispose of `WebResponse` values is a well-documented way to hang an app, for example.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks, I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should deal with this by implementing `IDisposible` on your class, the garbage collector will not automatically dispose of this object.

A simplified version is below, but check [this article for the best practice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and also [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300522/best-practices-for-handling-idisposable)

```
public class Session : IDisposible
{
    private HttpClient m_httpClient;

    public Session()
    {
       m_httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
       m_httpClient.Dispose();
    }
}
```